# Google map integration issue : "This site has exceeded its daily quota for maps

Tags: google-maps

I am getting the longitude and latitude from AJAX and giving me more 120 on every page load. Marking the result locations into google map and using browser key. It was working fine, but suddenly it stopped working and getting '**This site has exceeded its daily quota for maps. If you are the creator of this site, please visit the documentation to learn more**' error plus page hangs. It has been more than 24 hours, but the problem remains same. I tried to found out the solution but no luck and I changed new API key.

JS files:

```
<script src="http://open.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v7.2.s/mqa.toolkit.js?key=my-browser-key"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

JS code:

```
var map;
var infowindow;
var service;
var address     = "United Kingdom";
var latitude    = '51.497801';
var longitude   = '-0.065918';
var myLatlng    = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude); 
var geocoder    = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var markers     = '';
function initialize() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var getTeamsUrl = Routing.generate('getAllUsers',{});
    $.ajax({
        url      : getTeamsUrl,
        type     : 'POST', 
        data     : 'type=getAllUsers',
        datatype : 'json',
        async    : false,
        success : function(data){
            markers = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    });
    console.log(markers.length);
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);  /* latitude and longitude*/
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: myLatlng,
        panControl:true,    
        draggable: true,
        zoomControl:true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        scaleControl:false,
        rotateControl:true,
        mapTypeControl:true,    
        streetViewControl:true,
        overviewMapControl:true,
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ){
        name      = markers[i]['title']+' '+ markers[i]['first_name']+' '+ markers[i]['surname'];
        address   = markers[i]['address_1']+' '+ markers[i]['address_2']+', '+ markers[i]['city']+', '+ markers[i]['postcode'];
        longitude = markers[i]['longitude'];
        latitude  = markers[i]['latitude'];
        addMarkerOnMapUsingLatLng(latitude, longitude, name, address, '', 1);
    }

}


function addMarkerOnMapUsingLatLng(lat,lng, name, address, icon, selected){
    if(lat!='' && lng!=''){
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    }
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: myLatlng,
        panControl:true,    
        draggable: true,
        zoomControl:true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        scaleControl:false,
        rotateControl:true,
        mapTypeControl:true,    
        streetViewControl:true,
        overviewMapControl:true,
        navigationControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
        },
        streetViewControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
        },
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    if(selected==1){
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
        map.setCenter(myLatlng);
    }
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
        content: address,
        size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map, 
        title: name/*,
        icon : icon*/
    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        /* infoWindow.setContent(address); */
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Google Maps JavaScript API, the users of this [standard API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage#standard-usage-limits) is FREE until exceeding 25,000 map loads per 24 hours.

Just take note that for customers with active implementations of the Google Maps JavaScript API prior to [June 22, 2016](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update), quota exceptions may apply. In certain instances, map loads in excess of 25,000 per day may be allowed free of charge until October 12, 2016.

And if you exceed the free usage limits,the billing is $0.50 USD / 1000 additional requests, up to 100,000 per 24 hours.

Just check the link above to know more about Google Maps API Usage Limits